# Why does a miner still pay gas for a reverted transaction?

Tags: remix, mining, gas

I ran a contract [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140938/solidity-error-message-when-executing-smart-contract-the-constructor-should-be), I got the message "Transaction mined but execution failed". :

> [vm]from:0xca3...a733cto:Will.deceased() 0xbbf...732dbvalue:0
>   weidata:0x72f...af2d9logs:0hash:0xac5...6c5be  status     0x0 Transaction
>   mined but execution failed  transaction hash
>     0xac5e9ba96b61041582a22490d2947cc4d7f0f153255fb0ac273d931035c6c5be 
>   from  0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c  to  Will.deceased()
>   0xbbf289d846208c16edc8474705c748aff07732db  gas   3000000 gas
>   transaction cost  56697 gas   execution cost  35425 gas   hash
>     0xac5e9ba96b61041582a22490d2947cc4d7f0f153255fb0ac273d931035c6c5be 
>   input     0x72f...af2d9  decoded input    {}  decoded output  {}  logs    [] 
>   value     0 wei  transact to Will.deceased errored: VM error: revert.

Why is the miner still paid?

Answer (score 9):

A reverted transaction generally means that the logic of the smart contract being used failed or there's not enough gas to complete the transaction. The transaction was still executed by the miner, and any gas used prior to the transaction being reverted needs to be paid for. Based on this, the reverted transaction is still mined and included into the block that is published, but the state (of contracts) is not changed as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Because if not paid one could spam miners with setting insufficient gas limits, making miner execute the transaction and not get paid.

Think of this as the opportunity cost of the miner.